# findstr returning wrong error code inside block

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

When executing a loop, the errorlevel being referenced by `!errorlevel!` is returning 1 instead of 0 even though the statement is true. `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is enabled

I have tried rearranging the IF statements, tried using GOTO loops to put the error check outside of a function block. Tried `%ERRORLEVEL%` and `!ERRORLEVEL!`

The goal of this loop is to check a text file for a list of usernames, if the username exists in the file, add that user to the localadmins group.

```
rem == Count number of users in backup, create variable of user{num} for each username ==

set /p s=<"%custompath%\%uname%\users.txt"
set s=%s:~0,-1%
set /a counter=0
for %%a in (%s:,= %) do (
    set /a counter+=1 
    set user!counter!=%%a
    )

set /a count = 0

:CUSTOM_LOOP_ADMIN

rem == Adds user to Admin group on new computer if they were previously in local Administrators ==

if %count% LEQ %counter% (
    set /a count +=1
    IF NOT [!user%count%!]==[] (
        findstr /m "!user%count%!" "%custompath%\%uname%\Localadmins.txt" > nul
        IF !ERRORLEVEL!==0 (
            net localgroup Administrators NET\!user%count%! /add > nul 2> nul
            net localgroup Administrators !user%count%! /add > nul 2> nul
            echo.
            echo Added !user%count%! to local Administrators group
        )
    )

    goto :CUSTOM_LOOP_ADMIN )


GOTO :EOF
```

Expected result is `!ERRORLEVEL!` being equal to 0 if the username is in the text file, and returning non-0 if it isn't and continuing the loop.

**EDIT:**

I'm an idiot...

findstr is case-sensitive by default. resolved by using `findstr /m /i "sometext" "sample.txt" > nul`

Comment: How do you know the statement is true?

Comment: If I copy and paste the exact same statement outside of the batch file the ERRORLEVEL returns 0.

For example 

````findstr /m "user1" "c:\users.txt" > nul````
````echo %ERRORLEVEL%````

returns 0